# Are there any conditional rules for voluptuous?

Tags: python, validation, voluptuous

Is there any way to define conditional rules using voluptuous?

Here's the schema I have:

```
from voluptuous import Schema, All, Any

schema = Schema({
    'resolution': All(str, Any('1920x1080', '1280x720')),
    'bitrate': 20,
})
```

That's ok, but now I want to validate bitrate value based on resolution value. If I have `1920x1080` as resolution, than I need to be shure that bitrate is one of these values: 20, 16, 12, 8; and when it's `1280x720` then bitrate should be one of these: 10, 8, 6, 4.

How can I do that? There's info on the [project's github page](https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous) but I can't find my case there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voluptuous supports custom validation functions [1], but they only receive as input parameter the value being currently validated, not any other previously validated values. This means trying to do something like `'bitrate': (lambda bitrate, resolution: Any(20, 16, 12, 8) if bitrate in (...) else Any (10, 8, 6, 4))` will unfortunately not work.

You can try using `'bitrate': Any(20, 16, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4)` and then performing secondary validation yourself to make sure it's consistent with `resolution`.

Another approach could be to write a validator function for the complete dictionary, where the function would check both `resolution` and `bitrate` at the same time, though this way you'd be writing some code you normally get for free from voluptuous.

[1] https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous#validation-functions

Comment: That's really sad that it doesn't have this functionality.

Answer (score 10):

My solution for a similar problem is to do something like

```
from voluptuous import Schema, Any

lo_res = Schema({'resolution': '1280x720', 'bitrate': Any(10, 8, 6, 4)})
hi_res = Schema({'resolution': '1920x1080', 'bitrate': Any(20, 16, 12, 8)})
schema = Any(lo_res, hi_res)
```

This will give you proper validation, although the error messages can get a bit cryptic. You can write a more customized version of Any to improve the error messages.